# override @spring.showErrors to show single error?

Tags: freemarker

hi guys
i am new to freemarker and not very familiar with it
and i need a little help in overriding the following code, to show only one error instead of list of errors for each field:

```
<#macro showErrors separator classOrStyle="">
    <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
    <#if classOrStyle == "">
    <b>${error}</b>
    <#else>
    <#if classOrStyle?index_of(":") == -1><#assign attr="class"><#else><#assign attr="style"></#if>
    <span ${attr}="${classOrStyle}">${error}</span>
    </#if>${separator}
    </#list>
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show only the first error with the following macro:

```
<#macro showFirstError classOrStyle="">
    <#if (spring.status.errorMessages?has_content)>
        <#local error = spring.status.errorMessages[0] />
        <#if classOrStyle == "">
            <b>${error}</b>
        <#else>
            <#if classOrStyle?index_of(":") == -1>
                <#local attr="class">
            <#else>
                <#local attr="style">
            </#if>
            <span ${attr}="${classOrStyle}">${error}</span>
        </#if>
    </#if>
</#macro>
```